# Not allowed to change the ConnectionString

Tags: vb.net

I have this vb.net code:

```
conn6.ConnectionString = "server=" + global_variables.web_server_ip + "; user id=" + global_variables.web_server_username + "; password=" + global_variables.web_server_password + "; database=" + global_variables.web_server_database + "; "
conn6.Open()

SQL = "select calltype from billing group by calltype "
myCommand6.Connection = conn6
myCommand6.CommandText = SQL

reader6 = myCommand6.ExecuteReader

While reader6.Read
    cdr_call_type = reader6.GetString(0)
                    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'do VoIP bit
                    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If customerid_voip <> "" Or customerid_voip_new <> "" Then
       'do customer VoIP Bit, which means getting the latest value from billing table 
       TextBox1.Text = "Got VoIP - " + cdr_call_type + vbCrLf + TextBox1.Text
       Me.Refresh()

       conn3.ConnectionString = "server=" + global_variables.web_server_ip + "; user id=" + global_variables.web_server_username + "; password=" + global_variables.web_server_password + "; database=" + global_variables.web_server_database + "; "
       conn3.Open()

       SQL = "select reseller_bill, customer_bill, phone, calltype, timestamp, seconds from billing where calltype = '" + reader6.GetString(0) + "' AND (source='CDR' or source='' or source='VOIP') and (company='" + customerid_voip + "' or company='" + customerid_voip_new + "') "
       myCommand3.Connection = conn3
       myCommand3.CommandText = SQL

       reader3 = myCommand3.ExecuteReader

       While reader3.Read
          'do stuff here
       End While

       reader3.Close()
       conn3.Close()
   End If
End While

reader6.Close()
conn6.Close()
```

When I run the code, I get an error on line `conn3.Open()` saying:

> Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property while the connection (state=Open).

It works on the first loop, but when I get around to the second loop it stops and displays this error

Comment: The error message state that you cannot change the connectionstring when it is open. So you only need to close it, before modifying it.

Comment: I have closed it, using conn3.close()

Comment: close conn6 before trying to use another connection

Comment: conn6 is being closed

Comment: you are closing conn3 AFTER the while loop. but in the while loop you are changing the conn3 connection string - this is NOT valid.

Comment: You should definitly post only well formatted code because it's horrible to read for anyone trying to answer your question. Small coding advice: Do not use numbers as variable names, it makes your code absolutly unreadable.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here in this `while loop` you are trying to change the connectionString of an already defined connection, it can be avoided by creating a new connection each time within the loop as follows:

```
   While reader6.Read
   cdr_call_type = reader6.GetString(0)
   If customerid_voip <> "" Or customerid_voip_new <> "" Then
       TextBox1.Text = "Got VoIP - " + cdr_call_type + vbCrLf + TextBox1.Text
       Me.Refresh()
       Dim conn3 As New OdbcConnection '<--- declaring a new connection
       '<---- in each iteration connection is treated as a new one
       '<---- so initializing is not became a problem
       conn3.ConnectionString = "server=" + global_variables.web_server_ip + "; user id=" + global_variables.web_server_username + "; password=" + global_variables.web_server_password + "; database=" + global_variables.web_server_database + "; "
       conn3.Open()
       '<------
       ' Remaining codes comes here
       '<------
    End IF
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add some additional checking, before modifying it:

```
If conn3.State = ConnectionState.Open Then 
    conn3.Close()
End If
```